# Fastest way to calculate inverse consecutive numbers?

Tags: inverse, numerical-optimization

I am trying to find my way through a problem involving inverse numbers, for a game.

I need to **reduce the number of calculations** of the following product:

$\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{3}\times \dots \times\frac{1}{n}$

with n being variable.
I wondered if there were a fastest way than calculating every inverse.

### Question:

**is there a known formula to help?**

Note: I am not asking for a programming algorithm, just a theoretical one, an idea.

In advance, thank you,

### Edit:

the result must be precise to the closest natural.

Comment: Compute first $n!$ using Sterling, and invert afterwards.

Comment: How accurate/precise must your answer be?  For instance, when $n = 1\,234\,567$, a complete accurate answer is rather longish.

Comment: This product decreases rapidly in $n$. Can’t you simply store all of the values in your desired range?

Comment: I need an exact value

Comment: @URL: the problem being the range depends on the action of the user and can reach multiple millions

Comment: The reciprocal of your product grows as $\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n$. This grows pretty fast. Surely you won’t be able to handle large $n$. So, surely, there must be a small range in which $n$ can be. Why not just calculate those $n$ naively, and store them?

Comment: For the algorithm, I use a multiprecision library and the biggest number can be held in 1 million 64 bits words (8 bytes). So yes, it is pretty large.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Stirling was a really good idea until I saw the imprecision with big numbers (multiprecision)

Comment: @Kroma If you really need to manage big numbers, there’s probably not a whole lot much more you can do than calculate the value in the simplest way possible.

Comment: @URL: I am afraid..